# bootstrap input-group-lg button issue with input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I use input-group then every thing is ok but when I use `input-group-lg` then `Go` button goes to next line.

```
<div class="input-group-lg">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="http://">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default " type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

I solved it with `pull-left` in `input` but now its not displaying correctly in small resolutions

Comment: Oh..! what a mistake by me. Thanks a lot. Will you please post in answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input-group-lg` is a modifier class that needs to be used **in addition to** `input-group`, not *instead of* `input-group`. So your code snippet should be:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="http://">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default " type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Most of Bootstrap's classes obey this sort of pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this way:

I added "id=search_button" for my button

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button id="search_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">GO</button>
</span>
</div>
```

I apply this style to my button

```
#search_button {
    width: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

That's all